# How do I convert a 2D transformation matrix (for homogeneous coordinates) into 3D in the z=0 plane?

Tags: opengl, matrix, coordinates, coordinate-transformation, homogenous-transformation

I have a 3x3 transformation matrix for 2D homogeneous coordinates:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

I'd like to pass this to OpenGL (using `glMultMatrix`) in a 2D application, but OpenGL takes 4x4 matrices for 3D homogeneous coordinates. I'd like all coordinates transformed by my 4x4 matrix to end up with `x` and `y` the same as for the 3x3 matrix and with `z=0`.

I've tried to work it out. For a vector `x, y, 1` I'd end up with the transformed vector `ax + by + c, dx + ey + f, gx + hy + i`, so that means for a vector `x, y, 0, 1`, I'd want to end up with the tranformed vector `ax + by + c, dx + ey + f, 0, ?`. One matrix that would do this is (as far as I can tell):

```
a b 0 c
d e 0 f
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Is this correct? Does it work? I don't think this is the only matrix that will give the result I'm looking for, but I don't quite understand what should or shouldn't go in the third and fourth rows (and the fourth column).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the z-coordinate to be `0`, you have to pass a zero-row. Also, include the perspective part in the last row:

```
a b 0 c
d e 0 f
0 0 0 0
g h 0 i
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! If the vector I'm transforming has z=`0` already, I can leave the third row as `0 0 1 0` to make z in the same as z out, right?

Comment: Why not keep the 3rd row [0 0 1 0] leaving z unchanged? Identity would be to keep it this way. A zero vector in the 3rd row would mean a destructive projection transform. I understand that even if a point had z ≠ 0 it'll be made 0 while the other one will leave it unchanged. But is there any other reason other than that you had in mind? Just curious.

Comment: @legends2k No, it's really just because OP wanted all z-components to be 0 (as far as I understood).